# How can I submit image (formData) and string text variables (data) with one axios Post in Vue?

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, post, axios

I am trying to submit an image and other variable fields with one axios post in vue. I am having trouble combining the formData with regular variable string data.

I have tried append() but formData and data don't seem to work nicely together. I also tried just submitting the image right when the user adds the image as a seperate formData request but I realized that doesn't work because I need to check firstorNew() with my data submission.

```
create() {
            //this is normal data
            var data = {
                'organizationName': this.search,
                'organizationDescription': this.description,
                'facebookHandle': this.facebook,
                'instagramHandle': this.instagram,
                'twitterHandle': this.twitter,
                'organizationWebsite': this.organizerWebsite,
            };
            //this is image I want to add to data
            formData.append('avatar', this.avatar)

            axios.post('/create-your-event/' + this.event.slug + '/organizer', data).catch(error => {
                module.status = error.response.data.status;
            });
        },
```

This doesn't work and I get a null for my image. But if I try to let data = formData then none of my string text gets sent.

Comment: In what format is the `data` part expected server-side? Encoded as a single JSON object or as individual key-value pairs (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)?

Comment: hmm in laravel I am doing $request->file('avatar')->store('organizers', 'public');  Would that be individual key-value pairs?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood! I am accepting the "data' as key-value pairs in the controller:
```
organizer::firstOrNew(request()->validate([
            'organizationName' => 'required',
            'organizationDescription' => 'required',
            'instagramHandle' => '',
```

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/) you will find a detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I mostly dislike these kinds of answers, but since the post has a very clear explanation on a useful way of submitting data, I felt reasonable not taking the credit for the answer.

Comment: One thing that link does not demonstrate though is mixing data and file upload so while it's a pretty good resource, it doesn't actually answer this question

Comment: That would be an adition of one line of code like `formData.append('myfield', this.myfield)` which I assumed the author would figure out based on its own question. And again, I'd rather not take credit for an entire answer because of a single line of code having a detailed explanation on the post that I assume will help the author of the question. If you want, feel free to add your own answer with full explanation in your own words, I'm sure the author of the question would thank you a lot.

Comment: And just to be clear, I have no intention to promote any website or post.

Comment: It's ok but I think your answer should contain some examples. You could even add that _"one line of code"_ to build on the article

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I will surely take it into consideration.

Comment: As an extra piece of _"building on the article"_, I'm pretty sure you don't have to manually set the `Content-type` header when using `FormData`. Axios should set it to `multipart/form-data` for you automatically

Comment: I have tried to formData.append() but I couldn't get it to work with sending data like 
'organizationName': this.search,
'organizationDescription': this.description,

Comment: Have you tried `formData.append('organizationName', this.search)`?

Comment: I use 
create() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('avatar', this.avatar);
            formData.append('organizationName', this.search);
            formData.append('organizationDescription', this.description);


            axios.post('/create-your-event/' + this.event.slug + '/organizer', formData).catch(error => {
                module.status = error.response.data.status;
            });
        },
 the error  "Call to a member function store() on null",relating to controller $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('organizers', 'public');